# Silverlight scrollbar issues

Tags: c#, silverlight, scrollbar, scrollviewer

Hello I'm having some issues in Silverlight to make sure the scrollbar resets every time the user is navigated to another page. There is another issue I'm having where the scroll down arrow is not appearing when I debug my application. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: show some xaml code, what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to change the scroll-bar position

#### XAML

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollBar>
</ScrollViewer>
```

#### Code Behind

```
ScrollBar.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0d);
ScrollBar.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0d);
```

Change 0 to the position you want. 0 will bring it to the top.

As for the down arrow not appearing....that's a problem with your UI. Make sure the ScrollViewer doesn't extend off the screen.

Comment: I wish I could try it but now VS2010 is giving this problem with opening my XAML files. It won't load them up (smh) To a gander at this and see if you can help me out
http://i.imgur.com/xjHE8.png

Comment: upload your project somewhere and ill fix it.